# What is wrong with my code when calculating the quadratic equation?

Tags: python

```
print("Program to find roots of a quadratic equation.")
a = float(input("Enter 1st coefficient of equation(a) : "))
b = float(input("Enter 2nd coefficient of equation(b) : "))
c = float(input("Enter 3rd coefficient of equation(c) : "))
d = (b**2)-(4*(a*c))
if d > 0 or d < 0:
    d = d**(1/2)
    x1 = ((-b + d) / 2)  <- problem 1
    x2 = ((-b + d) / 2)  <- problem 2
    print("Coefficients of equation : ",x1,"and",x2)
else:
    x = (-b/(2*a)) <- unnecessary
    print("Coefficients of equation : ",x)
```

I am getting this as output:

> Program to find roots of a quadratic equation.
> Enter 1st coefficient of equation(a) : 5
> Enter 2nd coefficient of equation(b) : 5
> Enter 3rd coefficient of equation(c) : 5
> Coefficients of equation :  (-2.4999999999999996+4.330127018922194j) and (-2.4999999999999996+4.330127018922194j)
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ]

Comment: Note that your `x1` and `x2` are defined in exactly the same way.

Comment: Double-check your formula.  What happened to the `/ 2*a` in the first clause?  Why are x1 and x2 the same?

Comment: Please use a title that describes the problem you're having that others might search for. We're trying to build a Q&A reference for future visitors. What are you trying to achieve here and what's the expected/actual output and why?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

solve for the discriminate.  notice your x1 and x2 have the same equation.  this is the quadric function.  I corrected the formula.

```
import math

a=100
b=200
c=10
    
# calculate the discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

# find two solutions
x1 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
x2 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

print("Coefficients of equation {x1} and {x2}".format(x1=round(x1,2),x2=round(x2,2)))
```